# RxJS bindCallback on a Firestore callback function that expects a promise

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to bind the Firestore function `runTransaction`, which has a single param, which is the callback - a callback that should return a promise.

I've tried doing this:

```
const fs = firestore();
const runTransaction$ = bindCallback<firestore.Transaction>(fs.runTransaction.bind(fs));
const transaction$ = defer<firestore.Transaction>(() => runTransaction$());

const updateTimestamp = async (transaction: firestore.Transaction) => {
  const orderRef = this.orderDb.getDoc(orderUid).ref;
  const orderSnap = await transaction.get(orderRef);

  t.update(orderRef, { modified: Date.now() });
};

return transaction$
  .switchMap(updateTimestamp);
```

But it doesn't work, I keep getting the error: `Error: Transaction callback must return a Promise`. But it is a promise! An `async` function can't NOT return a promise. Besides, it works if I don't use `bindCallback` and just defer the promise normally.